# Java Spring Boot custom properties doesn't work in application.yml

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I'm following a tutorial on Java Spring Boot and the current topic is that one can use both `application.properties` and `application.yml`

So my `application.properties` looked like this:

```
spring.profiles.active=EN, cat
custom.username=user
custom.password=pass
```

I deleted it and created an `application.yml` instead. IntelliJ even marks it with the little green start button icon. `application.yml` looks like this:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: EN, cat
custom:
  username: user
  password: pass
```

But when I do the `custom` properties don't get recognized any more. The IDE marks them red and shows this error: "Key 'custom' is not expected here"

I wasn't sure if that's correct so I tried what the IDE suggested when using autocomplete to write `spring.profiles.active` which was writing the list elements like this:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active:
      - EN
      - cat
custom:
  username: user
  password: pass
```

But that also didn't help.

I'm not sure where to go from here. I've tried to research the issue, however the only hits I get that come somewhat close all just mention that it's possible to use `yml` instead of `properties` and some even use custom properties like I displayed above.

Is this maybe a version issue? My pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>myID</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myName</name>
    <description>myDescription</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

## Update

To answer the question Mark B posed in the comments. This is the error message:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-01-05T08:58:07.711+01:00 ERROR 5026 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in my.package.controllers.I18nController required a bean of type 'my.package.services.GreetingService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("i18nService")

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - User-defined bean
    - User-defined bean
    - User-defined bean method 'primaryGreetingService' in 'GreetingServiceConfig'
    - User-defined bean method 'propertyInjectedGreetingService' in 'GreetingServiceConfig'
    - User-defined bean method 'setterInjectedGreetingService' in 'GreetingServiceConfig'
    - User-defined bean


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'my.package.services.GreetingService' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

At first glance this looks like maybe I messed up something within the definition or configuration of my beans. However, when I revert my repository back to the state where I used the `application.properties` file as described above, everything works as expected.

I retook the steps to isolate the problem as much as possible.

All I did was:

1. delete `application.properties`
2. create `application.yml`

I have changed nothing else.

#### git status (translated and simplified):

```
On Branch master
Your Branch is in the same state as 'origin/master'.

Staged changes:
        deleted:       src/main/resources/application.properties
        new file:     src/main/resources/application.yml

Unstaged changes::
        changed:       src/main/resources/application.yml
```

`src/main/resources/application.yml` is staged as new file and then has unstaged changes because the IDE staged the new file on creation. Just to clear out any confusion. Though this shouldn't affect the outcome.

## Update 2

As suggested in the comments I tried to add `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom")`, but all that did was change the error slightly:

```
Error creating bean with name 'i18nController' defined in file
[/path/target/classes/my/package/controllers/I18nController.class]:
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0:
No qualifying bean of type 'my.package.services.GreetingService' available:
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("i18nService")}
```

Comment: Does the application actually give you errors that it can't find the properties during runtime? Or is it just the IDE flagging your custom properties as "unexpected"? For example in IntelliJ it has always flagged custom properties like that for me, because IntelliJ is trying to validate it against known Spring properties, but I can just ignore that warning from the IDE and the application runs fine.

Comment: `@Configuration`
`@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "custom")`

Comment: @MarkB The application doesn't run anymore as soon as I make the change. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @life888888 I tried adding the config properties but all that did was change the error a bit. It basically still says the same though. Thank you for the suggestion, I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Well error clearly says that Spring fails to inject some `i18nService` of which in one case you have multiple candidates, and on the other case no candidates, while exactly single candidate is expected. I think taht this might be related to the mess with bean profiles and how you are activating them

Comment: For satrters, remove spring.profile.active properties from your properties/yml files and set them from cli, then you will see where the problem is.

Comment: @Antoniossss I guess thats the symptom but the root of the problem is still not clear to me. Because as I stated, the only thing I changed was to go from one application file format to another.
I dont know what's best practice here but that's not the point. As I said Im currently working through a tutorial and that tutorial has the step where it shows me how to use yml instead of properties and I would like to get it to work like that. Thats why a workaround is not a satisfying solution to me here.

Comment: *(...)one application file format to another* and apparently you did it wrong, I would probably have problems myself If I would try to specify active profiles via yml as I dont know if it is a single string, array of strings etc. In props it sclear NAME1,NAME2 etc.

Comment: Have you tried using a .yml but with only the spring.profiles.active properties? This will allow you to assert the issue is with your properties, and not with the .yml not being recognized, or some other issue.

Comment: @MorBlau Only putting the `spring.profiles.active` in the yml file works. It compiles and chooses the appropriate profiles.

Comment: I cannot reproduce with the given pom file and a simple application comprising 2 user-defined beans/components. But your error message states that `GreetingService` cannot be injected. Find out why that is: are the multiple beans? no beans? beans only active with certain profiles? Can you (temporarily) change your application to to use the GreetingService as a dependency?

Comment: It seems that the problem is in some other parameters from the application file

Comment: @Nick There are none. Thats the literal file structure. The only difference is that I used the word "custom" here instead of the one I used in the real project that came from the tutorial: "guru".

Answer (score 0):

As you're using spring-boot-starter SnakeYAML library should be on your classpath, but please double-check with `mvn dependency:list`, search the output for a line `[INFO]    org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile -- module org.yaml.snakeyaml [auto]` .

If it's missing, then please add SnakeYAML dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml

Eclipse IDE has auto-convertion mechanism which converts properties into yaml format. Just right click on the file and click "convert" it works like a charm. I'm using Eclipse STS edition.

[image]

I guess that you're not sharing full properties file and there is a syntax error or something is missing in your yaml configuration. Please give a try with plugins which are available for InteliJ IDEA: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8000-properties-to-yaml-converter or online converters like: https://www.javainuse.com/app2yaml .

---

### **UPDATE:**

I Decided to reproduce your example code on my machine with exactly the same version of SpringBoot and Java. First of all I've created a properties files and tested (it worked fine) and then migrated properties file into YAML format and it also works fine with exactly the same result.

[image]

When it comes to unexpected key `custom` it only says that this key if unknown (more like warning then error), and you can define it in `META-INF` like below.

[image]

So as other comments suggest I'm sure that it's connected to code which relays on properties file in some hardcoded way (for example `@PropertySource` annotation, see also my comment below).

Comment: snakeyaml is part of my dependency list.
What I posted is in fact the full properties file.

Comment: did you try to use one of auto-conversion mechanism already ?

Comment: I tried the one you linked to. It produced the exact same yml file except for the order. So basically `custom` first and then `spring`

Comment: 1. do you use `@PropertySource` annotation somewhere in the project? Please search whole workspace. It might cause issues with migration from `properties` to `yaml`. 2. Upgrade springboot to a newer version as 2.2.2 has plenty of known vulnerabilities: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.2.2.RELEASE . Change to `2.2.13` at least. Maybe it will  also  fix your issue? Let me know :-)

Comment: please read  update of my answer @BenjaminBasmaci

Comment: There was no use of `@PropertySource` found  when I searched the workspace (ctrl+shift+f IntelliJ).
I tried to upgrade to 2.2.3 and 2.2.13 and the only notable change is that the IDE now also marks the "active" yaml input red aswell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251070/discussion-between-hakermsl-and-benjamin-basmaci).